# Summing weights based on string in large file

Tags: java, algorithm, file-io

I am pretty sure a modified/similar discussion might have already been done here but I want to present the exact problem i am facing with possible solution from my side. Then I want to hear from you guys that what would be better approach or how can I approve my logic.

**PROBLEM**
I have a huge file which contains lines. Each line is in following format `<weight>,<some_name>`. Now what I have to do is to add the weight of all the objects which has same name. The problem is

1. I don't know how frequent `some_name` exist in the file. it could appear only once or all of the millions could be it
2. It is not ordered
3. I am using File Stream (java specific, but it doesn't matter)

**SOLUTION 1**: Assuming that I have huge ram, What i am planning to do is to read file line by line and use the name as `key` in my hash_map. If its already there, sum it up otherwise add. It will cost me `m` ram (m = numer of lines in file) but overall processing would be fast

**SOLUTION 2**: Assuming that I don't have huge ram, I am going to do in batches. Read first 10,000 in hashtable, sum it up and dump it into the file. Do the for rest of the file. Once done processing file, I will start reading processed files and will repease this process to sum it up all.

What do you guys suggest here ?

Beside your suggestions, Can I do parallel file reading of the file ? I have access to FileInputStream here, Can i work with fileInputStream to make reading of file more efficient ?

Comment: Reading in parallel? With most hard-drives that will just slow things down ... a lot. Reading in parallel *with processing*, sure, that will work and isn't too difficult, but won't give too much of a speed boost (reading should be a lot slower than processing).

Answer (score 2):

The second approach is not going to help you: in order to produce the final output, you need sufficient amount of RAM to hold all keys from the file, along with a single `Integer` representing the count. Whether you're going to get to it in one big step or by several iterations of 10K rows at a time does not change the footprint that you would need at the end.

What would help is partitioning the keys in some way, e.g. by the first character of the key. If the name starts in a letter, process the file 26 times, the first time taking only the weights for keys starting in `'A'` and ignoring all other keys, the second time taking only `'B'`s, and so on. This will let you end up with 26 files that do not intersect.

Another valid approach would be using an [*external sorting algorithm*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) to transform an unordered file to an ordered one. This would let you walk the ordered file, calculate totals as you go, and write them to an output, even without the need for an in-memory table.

As far as optimizing the I/O goes, I would recommend using the [`newBufferedReader(Path path,Charset c)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#newBufferedReader%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29) method of the `java.nio.file.Files` class: it gives you a `BufferedReader` that is optimized for reading efficiency.

Comment: "The second approach is not going to help you" ... unless they're sorted, in which case you can do a merge-sort-like process. Writing a hash to file should essentially end up with a sorted list, albeit sorted by hash, mod something.

Comment: @Dukeling OP states that the entries are not ordered (see bullet point #2).

Comment: Just because the original file isn't sorted doesn't mean you can't sort the intermediary files.

Comment: @Dukeling Sorting intermediate files is not going to help, because multiple files may end up with data that belongs to the same key.

Comment: Yes, but you can step through multiple files at the same time, streaming to another file as you go, thus only keeping each file position in memory.

Comment: @Dukeling That's effectively a multifile external merge sort - a 100% valid approach, but it is different from what the OP has suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Is the file static when you do this computation? If so, then you could disk sort the file based on the name and add up the consecutive entries.